# Pandas: reindex and interpolate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with `MultiIndex` columns and regular index:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/A1bFw0R5', 
                 index_col=0, header=[0, 1], sep='\t')
```

[image: Dataframe]

```
df.plot(marker='.')
```

[image: Real]

## Question

I'd need to interpolate my index and have a better precision. It should be fairly easy as the columns are all perfectly linear. However, when I reindex (unioning with the previous index so that I don't lose my initial points), I get a result obviously wrong.

What's the proper way to do so?

```
new_index = df.index.union(np.arange(0.11, 0.21, 0.01)) 
df.reindex(new_index)\
  .interpolate(how='linear')\
  .plot(marker='.')
```

[image: Wrong]

Comment: Those kinks are caused by 0.143 and 0.177 in the index, so what do you want to do with those?

Comment: Well I'd like to keep them. Can't Pandas interpolate properly when the index isn't evenly paced?

Comment: Have you tried using `method="nearest"` in the `reindex()` function?

Comment: Just tried, gives the same exact result as `linear`